# Recipes package: Use grepl to populate the model formula using recipes()

Tags: r, r-recipes

I am using the Ames Housing Data and I want to use all the variables with the suffix "SF" in my recipe, I want to use `step_pca()` on the variables that are measure by squared feet.

I used `reformulate()` to no avail:

```
SF <- reformulate(grep("SF", names(ames), value = TRUE), 
              response = 'Sale_Price')
simple_ames <- 
  recipe(SF + Neighborhood + Gr_Liv_Area + Year_Built + Bldg_Type + Latitude, 
                        data = ames_train) %>% 
  step_log(Gr_Liv_Area, base = 10) %>% 
  step_other(Neighborhood, threshold = 0.01) %>%
  step_dummy(all_nominal_predictors()) %>% 
  step_interact(~ Gr_Liv_Area:starts_with('Bldg_Type_')) %>% 
  step_ns(Latitude, deg_free = 20) %>% 
  step_pca(matches('(SF$)|(Gr_Liv'))
```

Also used `grep()` directly into the formula

```
 simple_ames <- 
   recipe(Sale_Price ~ paste(grep("SF"), collapse = '+') + Neighborhood + 
   Gr_Liv_Area + Year_Built + Bldg_Type + Latitude, data = ames_train) %>% 
   step_log(Gr_Liv_Area, base = 10) %>% 
   step_other(Neighborhood, threshold = 0.01) %>%
   step_dummy(all_nominal_predictors()) %>% 
   step_interact(~ Gr_Liv_Area:starts_with('Bldg_Type_')) %>% 
   step_ns(Latitude, deg_free = 20) %>% 
   step_pca(matches('(SF$)|(Gr_Liv'))
```

I am using the examples from Tidy Modelling with R, https://www.tmwr.org/recipes chapter 8.4.4 (authors do not explain a efficient way to insert all those variables into recipe)

Thanks

Comment: Relevant: https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-to-make-large-formula-with-recipes/179105 ?

Comment: @jared_mamrot the solution is there, thank you

Comment: You're welcome; glad you solved your problem :)

Answer (score 3):

In the recipes package only the selector functions from recipes and tidyselect are allowed. Custom functions will fail. To do what you want to do try:

```
step_pca(ends_with("SF") , contains("Gr_Liv"))
```

If you insist on a regex, remember that tidyselect `matches` (which recipes utilises) uses stringr style regex and the following should work:

```
step_pca(matches("SF$|Gr_Liv"))
```

You can always test your selector if you use tidyselect selectors within recipes by actually applying it to the data you are using e.g. `ames |> select(matches("SF$|Gr_Liv"))`. That helps to make sure that you operate on the predictors you want.

See also `?recipes::selections` for a more thorough explanation.

Answer (score -1):

For anyone who would have a similar problem, this is the solution:

First, input all the dataframe variables into the recipe, second, use the `remove_role()` function to select all the variable you do not want as predictors (consider that if you do not do this, all dataframe variables will be considered as predictors in model) and third, do the pre-processing as planned.

```
 simple_ames <- recipe(Sale_Price ~ ., data = ames_train) %>% 
  remove_role(-ends_with('SF'), -c('Neighborhood', 'Gr_Liv_Area', 
 'Year_Built', 'Bldg_Type', 'Latitude'), old_role = 'predictor') 
 %>% 
  step_log(Gr_Liv_Area, base = 10) %>% 
  step_other(Neighborhood, threshold = 0.01) %>%
  step_dummy(all_nominal_predictors()) %>% 
  step_interact(~ Gr_Liv_Area:starts_with('Bldg_Type_')) %>% 
  step_ns(Latitude, deg_free = 20) %>% 
  step_pca(ends_with("SF") , contains("Gr_Liv"))
```

Comment: That doesn’t really answer your initial question, but is more a related but different problem